# appendPath to produce hollow object Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

So I am trying to create a segment of a circle ie a pie slice then use a circle to remove the majority of the wedge leaving an outer arc.

This is what I have so far[image]
As you can see it is messing up somewhere!

I achieve this using the following code:-

```
UIBezierPath* theStroke = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:mainCutout cornerRadius:theRadius];
[theOrangeColor setFill];
theStroke.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;
[theStroke fill];
[theStroke stroke];
[theStroke setMiterLimit:2.0];


UIBezierPath *aSegment = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
aSegment.usesEvenOddFillRule = YES;

[aSegment moveToPoint:theCenter];
[aSegment addLineToPoint:theCenter];
[aSegment addArcWithCenter:theCenter radius:theRadius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
[aSegment addLineToPoint:theCenter];
[aSegment appendPath:theStroke];

[theRedColor setFill];
[aSegment fill];
[aSegment stroke];
[aSegment closePath];
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see how you can use the even-odd filling rule to remove that parts of the sector.

But you can easily draw the "outer slice" of the segment by drawing two arc segments with different radii. Example:

```
CGPoint theCenter = CGPointMake(100., 100.);
CGFloat innerRadius = 50.;
CGFloat outerRadius = 60.;
CGFloat startAngle = M_PI;
CGFloat endAngle = 3*M_PI/2;

UIBezierPath *aSegment = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[aSegment addArcWithCenter:theCenter radius:innerRadius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
[aSegment addArcWithCenter:theCenter radius:outerRadius startAngle:endAngle endAngle:startAngle clockwise:NO];
[aSegment closePath];
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
[aSegment fill];
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Super over complicating of such a simple issue!

Comment: One thing that this takes advantage of is the fact that `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:`, and other, similar methods in both UIBezierPath and its Cocoa cousin (and similar functions in Quartz, for that matter), will implicitly `lineto` from your last current point. From that code, it looks like it'll even implicitly `moveto` the arc's start point if there wasn't a current point already. One end of the drawn arc is such an implicit segment (between the two arcs); the other is provided by `closePath`, returning to the first arc's start point.

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification in *@Martin R*'s code, 
If you can specify the **lineWidth of the CALayer** over which you gonna draw your arc segment, a single "addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:" will do the job for you.

> You have to use stroke instead of fill.(i.e.)just use strokeColor

**Eg:**

```
static inline double radians (double degrees)
{
    return degrees * M_PI/180;
}

CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
CGFloat radius = 50.0;
shapeLayer.path = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:centerPoint radius:radius startAngle:radians(startingAngle) endAngle:radians(endingAngle) clockwise:1 ]CGPath ];
[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

This may be useful to someone...